# Retain count -1: can somebody explain to me?

Tags: release, init, retain, counting, alloc

The image explain the problem (it isn't absurd??!)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `-retainCount` method returns an unsigned integer, so it, by definition, cannot be negative. You are printing it in the wrong form, because you wrongly assumed it was a signed integer. It is actually `NSUIntegerMax`.

Second, `-retainCount` is not useful in general. Even [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) says:

> Do not use this method. (required)
>
> ...
>
> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues.
>   Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in
>   order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease
>   pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it
>   is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

Third, classes can override `-retainCount` and return something custom. This is usually done in classes with custom memory management characteristics, which cannot be described well with a retain count. This is the case here because string objects from string literals are statically allocated, and exist for the whole lifetime of the program. They are not memory-managed. Therefore, they return a bogus retain count of `NSUIntegerMax`.